# $2x + y = c$ versus $2(x-1)+1(y-2)=k$ for the equation of planes

Tags: multivariable-calculus

My question comes from a Khan Academy video [here.](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus/applications-of-multivariable-derivatives/tangent-planes-and-local-linearization/v/controlling-a-plane-in-space) It aims to teach me how to better understand how one takes information from a plane and turns it into an equation.

I had no problems up until, roughly, the $7$ minute mark.

His equation for the plane was $$f(x,y) = 2x + y + c$$

Which works fine for me. In this case it has the derivatives we need, so with a constant we should be good for freedom of positioning in the space, for lack of a better explanation (the same reason we need a constant for a line with first derivative $m=2$. We don't know whether where it crosses the y-axis). We could find the constant by taking the point $(1,2,3)$ and have an equation. However, he then expressed it as follows:

$$f(x,y)= 2(x-1)+1(y-2) +k$$

And I can't seem to understand his logic behind it. It resembles the equation for a circle for me, so I can tell it may have something to do with where the "center" of the plane is oriented, but he states that $k = 3$ in this case.

Now, I know $c$ and $k$ are different, and we can find this discrepancy, since these represent the same function, so thus must be equal.

$$2x+y+c = 2x -2 + y -2 + k$$
$$-4+k = c$$

$$k = c + 4$$

If we evaluate $c$ using the point $(1,2,3)$ we arrive at $3 = 2 + 2 + c$, so thus $c=-1$ and $k=3$ is thus valid. Therefore, his equation is fine with that constant (and the derivatives are also consistent) but I don't understand his reasoning for expressing it this way. He says that he wants to "evaluate it at the point $(1,2)$" so doing this will make it "as easy as possible", and then plugs the point in to the equation in question gives $3 = 0 + k$.

Basically, I know that what he's done is perfectly consistent but I don't know how he got it and why this is a better way to express this function.

Answer (score 0):

A plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ can characterized by its "orientation", a normal vector $\langle a,b,c \rangle$, and a point that it passes through, $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$. The equation for the plane is then

$$a(x - x_0) + b(y - y_0) + c(z - z_0) = 0$$

This is a generalization of a line, not a circle, in $\mathbb{R}^2$. The equation for a line in $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be written as

$$a(x - x_0) + b(y - y_0) = 0$$

which might give you some insight into why 
$$a(x - x_0) + b(y - y_0) + c(z - z_0) = 0$$
 describes a plane.

For your example we can use $\langle 2,1,0 \rangle$ for the normal vector and $(1,2,3)$ for the point. If you plug this information in you'll get

$$2(x - 1) + 1(y - 2) + 0(z - 3) = 0$$

which can be rearranged to

$$2x + y = 4$$

Comment: I'm aware of the vector definition of a plane, but I'm still familiarizing myself with the idea of a plane in the typical, row picture idea. To be honest, I was never really presented with the equation for a line you presented to me, and as such I'm unable to connect that in order to get insight as to why the equation of a plane is represented in that way. I'm really only familiar with the $y=mx+b$ interpretation. So, I'm not sure how the equation for a line you gave me came to me, and am unable to connect to planes, and I'm also unaware as to how it's beneficial or perhaps favored.

Comment: One form of a line is point-slope form: $y - y_0 = m (x - x_0)$, which you can rewrite as $m(x - x_0) - (y - y_0) = 0$.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the intuition behind this. Is this necessary to explain in order to understand the answer to my question?

Comment: I think so, especially since understanding equations of planes will be harder if you don't understand equations of lines. Start with finding the slope between $(x_0,y_0)$ and $(x,y)$: $m = \dfrac{y - y_0}{x - x_0}$. Multiply by $x - x_0$ to get $m(x - x_0) = y - y_0$.